# LinkedIn OAuth 2, redirect_uri not called if CAPTCHA was shown to user

Tags: android, oauth, linkedin-api, captcha

Last week I updated our Android application from using the old legacy OAuth API (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2-legacy) to the new V2 version (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2).

On the surface this appears to work, and my redirect_url is being directed to correctly, however, if LinkedIn decides to verify a user via a CAPTCHA, the redirect_url is not returned, and the user is taken to a LinkedIn home page.

To reproduce this:

1. Start OAuth with the call to https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization
2. Enter in an email, but then a bunch of wrong passwords. Do this until you trigger the CAPTCHA flow.
3. Complete CAPTCHA. When redirected back to login page, enter in correct password

This results in the following URLs being called from LinkedIns side, when going through the CAPTCHA flow:

1. https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=
2. https://www.linkedin.com/uas/consumer-captcha-v2?challengeId=
3. https://www.linkedin.com/nhome/?trk= <-- OH OH, this should be a login success, followed by our redirect_url

For note, the auth flow that doesn't go through CAPTCHA looks like this and DOES work.

1. https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization-postlogin?app_id=
2. https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=%2Foauth%2Fv2%2Flogin-success%3Fapp_id
3. https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/login-success?app_id=
4. http://www.ourCoolCallback/linkedin?code= <-- YAY

Has anyone seen this issue? Does anyone know how to get around this, as I am completely at a loss. It seems as if the redirection is getting lost on the LinkedIn side of things. Since this used to work for us using Legacy OAuth - I am guessing something is borked LinkedIn side? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You can enable the JavaScript. It will enable the CAPTCHA in webview without any problem:

Following is the code with screenshots showing successful login with CAPTCHA.

```
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]